# flutter: Access two firecast collection in same widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter, I am trying to consume two collections in firebase firecast in same widget. but I am unable to fit it.

Flutter document provides a single StreamBuilder fits in a widget reference

```
return new StreamBuilder<Event>(
  stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('schedules').onValue,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
    if (!event.hasData)
      return new Center(child: new Text('Loading...'));
      Map<String, Map> schedules = event.data.snapshot.value;
     // Do something with the list of schedules
})
```

My Desired Output:

[image: trying to achieve something like this.]

I am trying to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a Column and add another StreamBuilder:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder(...),
    StreamBuilder(...),
  ],
)
```